# ActionBarSherlock - Consistent tabs through out entire project - Is there a simple way to do this?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I'm looking to have 3 or 4 tabs, which will each lead to a different activity. However, so far it appears that I am going to have to set up the tabs in each individual activity.

Is there a simple way to declare a set of tabs under the actionbar, and keep the state consistent, even when activities are switched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Fragment`s](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). This will require one activity and `n` fragments (where `n` is the number of tabs).

Jake Wharton has provided some [sample code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java) illustrating how you can implement this behavior.